# How to export data from more than one tables in one csv file without joins in php

Tags: php, mysql, csv, export

I want to export data in one csv file using php from three different tables.

If I join the tables it export only that parent data which has child data, but I want export all parent child data and also I want all data in one file.

**I don't want to use joins**

Is the any solution for this?

here is my query

```
$query = "SELECT plist.*, psong.*, prate.* 
          FROM " . $pre . "foo_playlists As plist 
          Inner Join " . $pre . "foo_songs As psong 
          On plist.playlist_name = psong.playlist_name 
          Inner Join " . $pre . "foo_rating As prate 
          On psong.song_id = prate.song_id";
```

Comment: the fact you don't want to use joins doesn't mean that joins shouldn't be used. if you don't want, just run n queries in a foreach loop over the parent records to fetch the children records.

Comment: Please consider to add some example data of both tables and the desired csv export.

Comment: there are many types of joins: left , right, natural. give it a read

Comment: put your existing code you are using?

Comment: @SKRocks see now i edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't imagine why you "don't want to use" JOINs, it's a little like asking how to drive a nail, but you don't want to use a hammer.  Nonetheless, if you want 3 tables, and don't want to use the right tool for the job, you'll need to read each of them individually, writing the output to a single file,

OR (more efficiently AND more correctly),

Change your sample SQL to LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN - that's *why* there's a LEFT JOIN.
In your case, **it will include ALL rows from `foo_playlists`**, and either a matching row from `foo_songs`, or `null` if there isn't a match, and the same  from `foo_rating`.

```
SELECT plist.*, psong.*, prate.* 
FROM " . $pre . "foo_playlists As plist 
LEFT JOIN " . $pre . "foo_songs As psong On plist.playlist_name = psong.playlist_name 
LEFT JOIN " . $pre . "foo_rating As prate On psong.song_id = prate.song_id
```

See this [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins) to clearly explain how to include/exclude data from the two tables being JOINed.

Answer (score 2):

I've a problem.When I executed this query, only table_1 showed on result (10 rows) .But table_1 and table_2 showed when exporting on csv with php (20 rows)

```
SELECT table_1.*, table_2.* 
FROM mytable_1 AS table_1 
LEFT  JOIN  mytable_2  AS table_2
    ON table_1.id = table_2.id
        AND table_1.name = table_2.name limit 10
```

Comment: “If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the Ask Question button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.”